# After migrating with duplicator all scripts are still tied to old CDN

Tags: plugins

Having issues here after using duplicator, I migrated my wordpress site from godaddy managed wordpress to a linux VPS. Everything seems to have copied over properly, but the whole site display is broken. I figured out with inspect element that every link seems to be tied back to, not the domain, but some sort of cdn? That's the IP address of the original server I believe (and the myftpupload is the original server address before it was tied to the domain name). It looks like this:

```
src="http://secureservercdn.net/198.71.233.44/omd.4c7.myftpupload.com/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js?ver=5.2.4&time=1571759864"
```

When I edit everything before wp-includes to be the correct domain (which did not change in the migration) it works.

I feel like I've tried just about everything (search and replace, mysql replace, url update, permalink reset, etc) but nothing seems to have an effect on changing links in my actual source code for the main page. I did use Hummingbird to cache the original site, could it be related? Maybe I needed to disable the CDN before duplicating the site? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: I just re-duplicated the site after disabling CDN and Hummingbird. The site works, but I think that's only because it's still connected to the managed wordpress. The links still connect back to the original cdn. Here is the site btw: http://coconailspact.com/

Comment: Have you confirmed your DNS changes have fully propagated? If you just switched settings, it may take a day or two before you're fully switched to the new site. If you've confirmed this, you can check with both hosts to see what CDNs they use, and check whether any of your plugins use CDNs. You may also want to contact the new host, and/or Duplicator support, and ask them about it as they may have a fix for it.

Comment: @WebElaine thanks for your response. I just had a thought that maybe I could duplicate the page, or reapply the theme. But even with those methods it continues to connect to the old CDN. The new host is still godaddy and I don't have priority support, although I do have a managed server. The strange part is the fact that I can change the links from the cdn/ip link to my domain and it still works fine. I still have a site on the managed wordpress account that I need to transfer and the same thing works. If I could just change all the links in the source to be the domain I would be set...

Comment: I was under the impression Duplicator handled all the URL changes, but maybe it didn't have a setting for you to enter the CDN and have it update the URLs? You could try a different database migration plugin that will search and replace all the old URLs in content etc.

Comment: @WebElaine Thank you for your continued responses. Soooo I looked at the source on my other site and it had the same CDN stuff. I disabled the CDN and cleared the cache and wouldn't you know it, it reset the URLs in the source to the base domain. I transferred the site to my server and everything works! I'm going to see if I can reset the cache a few more times on the other domain and get it to clear and replace the CDN urls with the base domain name. Such a headache! 
Also, question: I'm still seeing the 'managed wordpress' dropdown even when the site is transferred to my hosting. Problem?

Comment: Well, I went on the phone with GoDaddy hosting and thiiiink I figured out the issue. It's legitimately still related to cache. No matter what I do I can't seem to clear my cache of this website. It was cleared (cdn links) for the hosting agent and when I go to http://coconailspact.com/?nocache=1 the cdn is gone! What the hell. So I'm transferring the site over again and hoping that this crap clears soon. Will test on a different browser/device/network and report back.

Comment: Site loads cached version even on mobile device, on 4g, on a different browser. Seriously wtf.